# Reading 'binary' bytes from a file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bit-manipulation, byte

Consider a file that contains binary data represented as bytes:

```
with open('foo', 'rb') as f:
    bs = f.read()
    print(bs)
    # b'\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01'...
```

The bytes can only have either `0` or `1` values.

What is the most performant way to take a group of 32 bit/bytes and parse them into a (32-bit) integer? The [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module is probably what I need but I couldn't find an immediate way to do this.

Alternative methods that involve casting bytes into chars and then parsing the integer from a bitstring e.g. `int('01010101...', 2)` don't perform as fast as I need them to for my use case.

Comment: So you want to read 32 bits and interpret that as an int? Does the file only contain 32 bits or is it many 32-bit numbers?

Comment: The file contains many numbers if it matters for the solution

Comment: @YuvalAdam, did you try struct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Workaround Solutions

Considering the test number `101010...`:

```
b = b'\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00'
print(0b10101010101010101010101010101010)
# 2863311530
```

Map bytes to string, then parse the int:

```
s = ''.join(map(lambda x: chr(x+48), b))
i = int(s, 2)
print(i)
# 2863311530
```

Iterate over the bytes and build the integer using bitshifts:

```
idx = 0
tmp = 0
for bit in b:
    tmp <<= 1
    tmp |= bit
    idx += 1
    if idx == 32:
        print(tmp)
        idx = 0
        tmp = 0
# 2863311530
```

Comment: You said the `int(..., 2)` doesn't perform fast enough, but it's likely the `map` + `lambda` combination that's taking up the most time. Try `s = ''.join([chr(x+48) for x in b])`, that should give you a significant speedup.